# Pushing to Heroku: Slug compilation failed: failed to compile Ruby app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I just configured Heroku for AWS, because I'm working through a tutorial in which an app is developed that lets users upload pins, and the images will be hosted on AWS. http://lisa-pinteresting.herokuapp.com/

Everything seemed to go alright with the configuration. I tried to push to heroku and got this, saying it failed to compile Ruby App. I'm not sure why it was installing things, maybe this has something to do with AWS.

```
 Lisa:pinteresting admin-lisa$ git push heroku master
Fetching repository, done.
Counting objects: 61, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (33/33), done.
Writing objects: 100% (43/43), 277.18 KiB | 345 KiB/s, done.
Total 43 (delta 16), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
-----> Installing dependencies using 1.5.2
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.......
       Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Using rake (10.3.2)
       Using minitest (4.7.5)
       Using i18n (0.6.9)
       Using multi_json (1.10.1)
       Using thread_safe (0.3.3)
       Using tzinfo (0.3.39)
       Using erubis (2.7.0)
       Using rack (1.5.2)
       Using mime-types (1.25.1)
       Using polyglot (0.3.4)
       Using builder (3.1.4)
       Using activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
       Using arel (4.0.2)
       Using json (1.8.1)
       Using bcrypt (3.1.7)
       Using coffee-script-source (1.7.0)
       Using sass (3.2.19)
       Using execjs (2.0.2)
       Using thor (0.19.1)
       Using orm_adapter (0.5.0)
       Using hike (1.2.3)
       Using pg (0.17.1)
       Using bundler (1.5.2)
       Using tilt (1.4.1)
       Using rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.2)
       Using rails_stdout_logging (0.0.3)
       Using treetop (1.4.15)
       Using rack-test (0.6.2)
       Using warden (1.2.3)
       Using rdoc (4.1.1)
       Using activesupport (4.0.2)
       Using bcrypt-ruby (3.1.5)
       Using coffee-script (2.2.0)
       Using uglifier (2.5.0)
       Using bootstrap-sass (3.1.1.1)
       Using sprockets (2.11.0)
       Using rails_12factor (0.0.2)
       Using mail (2.5.4)
       Using actionpack (4.0.2)
       Using activemodel (4.0.2)
       Using jbuilder (1.5.3)
       Using sdoc (0.4.0)
       Using actionmailer (4.0.2)
       Using railties (4.0.2)
       Using sprockets-rails (2.0.1)
       Using activerecord (4.0.2)
       Using coffee-rails (4.0.1)
       Using devise (3.1.2)
       Using jquery-rails (3.1.0)
       Using sass-rails (4.0.3)
       Using rails (4.0.2)
       Using turbolinks (2.2.2)
       Installing climate_control (0.0.3)
       Installing uuidtools (2.1.4)
       Installing cocaine (0.5.4)
       Installing paperclip (3.5.4)
       Installing nokogiri (1.5.11)
       Installing aws-sdk (1.20.0)
       Your bundle is complete!
       Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
       It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
       Bundle completed (29.07s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       rake aborted!
       NameError: undefined local variable or method `config' for main:Object
       /tmp/build_32e2ee0e-d98a-4fbf-9662-a0c7aee58685/config/environments/production.rb:86:in `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_32e2ee0e-d98a-4fbf-9662-a0c7aee58685/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
       /tmp/build_32e2ee0e-d98a-4fbf-9662-a0c7aee58685/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
       /tmp/build_32e2ee0e-d98a-4fbf-9662-a0c7aee58685/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
       /tmp/build_32e2ee0e-d98a-4fbf-9662-a0c7aee58685/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
       /tmp/build_32e2ee0e-d98a-4fbf-9662-a0c7aee58685/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:591:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
       /tmp/build_32e2ee0e-d98a-4fbf-9662-a0c7aee58685/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:590:in `each'
       /tmp/build_32e2ee0e-d98a-4fbf-9662-a0c7aee58685/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:590:in `block in <class:Engine>'
       /tmp/build_32e2ee0e-d98a-4fbf-9662-a0c7aee58685/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
       /tmp/build_32e2ee0e-d98a-4fbf-9662-a0c7aee58685/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
       /tmp/build_32e2ee0e-d98a-4fbf-9662-a0c7aee58685/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_32e2ee0e-d98a-4fbf-9662-a0c7aee58685/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
       /tmp/build_32e2ee0e-d98a-4fbf-9662-a0c7aee58685/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
       /tmp/build_32e2ee0e-d98a-4fbf-9662-a0c7aee58685/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_32e2ee0e-d98a-4fbf-9662-a0c7aee58685/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
       /tmp/build_32e2ee0e-d98a-4fbf-9662-a0c7aee58685/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
       /tmp/build_32e2ee0e-d98a-4fbf-9662-a0c7aee58685/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_32e2ee0e-d98a-4fbf-9662-a0c7aee58685/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
       /tmp/build_32e2ee0e-d98a-4fbf-9662-a0c7aee58685/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
       /tmp/build_32e2ee0e-d98a-4fbf-9662-a0c7aee58685/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
       /tmp/build_32e2ee0e-d98a-4fbf-9662-a0c7aee58685/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
       /tmp/build_32e2ee0e-d98a-4fbf-9662-a0c7aee58685/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in `require_environment!'
       /tmp/build_32e2ee0e-d98a-4fbf-9662-a0c7aee58685/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:250:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
       /tmp/build_32e2ee0e-d98a-4fbf-9662-a0c7aee58685/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in define'
       Tasks: TOP => environment
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app

To git@heroku.com:lisa-pinteresting.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:lisa-pinteresting.git'
```

My gem file looks like this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


gem 'rails', '4.0.2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
gem 'devise', '~> 3.1.0.rc2'
gem 'paperclip', '~> 3.0'
gem 'aws-sdk', '~>1.20.0'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

group :development, :test do
     gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
     gem 'pg'
     gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

When I run heroku logs --tail I get:

```
Lisa:pinteresting admin-lisa$ heroku log --tail
/Users/admin-lisa/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/updater.rb:164: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777
 !    `log` is not a heroku command.
 !    Perhaps you meant `logs`.
 !    See `heroku help` for a list of available commands.
Lisa:pinteresting admin-lisa$ heroku log
 !    `log` is not a heroku command.
 !    Perhaps you meant `logs`.
 !    See `heroku help` for a list of available commands.
Lisa:pinteresting admin-lisa$ heroku logs --tail
/Users/admin-lisa/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/helpers.rb:93: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777
2014-05-29T19:19:36.988188+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/pins/1 host=lisa-pinteresting.herokuapp.com request_id=3712b02a-d7f9-4b21-83ea-208683b0d5d6 fwd="50.143.161.142" dyno=web.1 connect=13ms service=194ms status=500 bytes=1543
2014-05-29T19:19:36.794245+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/pins/1" for 50.143.161.142 at 2014-05-29 19:19:36 +0000
2014-05-29T19:19:36.795900+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
2014-05-29T19:19:36.978593+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pins/show.html.erb within layouts/application (164.7ms)
2014-05-29T19:19:36.978580+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pins/show.html.erb within layouts/application (164.7ms)
2014-05-29T19:19:36.978698+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 183ms
2014-05-29T19:19:36.794257+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/pins/1" for 50.143.161.142 at 2014-05-29 19:19:36 +0000
2014-05-29T19:19:36.795868+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PinsController#show as HTML
2014-05-29T19:19:36.795905+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
2014-05-29T19:19:36.978700+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 183ms
2014-05-29T19:19:36.980505+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-05-29T19:19:36.795862+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PinsController#show as HTML
2014-05-29T19:19:36.980511+00:00 app[web.1]:      7: 
2014-05-29T19:19:36.980508+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `pin' for #<#<Class:0x007ff9f4a7af80>:0x007ff9f4b73cc0>):
2014-05-29T19:19:36.980510+00:00 app[web.1]:      6: </p>
2014-05-29T19:19:36.980513+00:00 app[web.1]:      8: <% if @pin.user == current_user %>
2014-05-29T19:19:36.980514+00:00 app[web.1]:      9:   <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_pin_path(pin) %>
2014-05-29T19:19:36.980516+00:00 app[web.1]:     10: <% end %>
2014-05-29T19:19:36.980518+00:00 app[web.1]:     11: <%= link_to 'Back', pins_path %>
2014-05-29T19:19:36.980543+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-05-29T19:19:36.980520+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/pins/show.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_pins_show_html_erb___2646305287935589538_70355765611620'
2014-05-29T19:19:36.980541+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-05-29T19:19:36.980557+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `pin' for #<#<Class:0x007ff9f4a7af80>:0x007ff9f4b73cc0>):
2014-05-29T19:19:36.980548+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-05-29T19:19:36.980560+00:00 app[web.1]:      7: 
2014-05-29T19:19:36.980559+00:00 app[web.1]:      6: </p>
2014-05-29T19:19:36.980564+00:00 app[web.1]:     10: <% end %>
2014-05-29T19:19:36.980561+00:00 app[web.1]:      8: <% if @pin.user == current_user %>
2014-05-29T19:19:36.980563+00:00 app[web.1]:      9:   <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_pin_path(pin) %>
2014-05-29T19:19:36.980566+00:00 app[web.1]:     11: <%= link_to 'Back', pins_path %>
2014-05-29T19:19:36.980567+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/pins/show.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_pins_show_html_erb___2646305287935589538_70355765611620'
2014-05-29T19:19:36.980568+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-05-29T19:19:36.980570+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-05-29T19:19:49.151948+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/pins/3 host=lisa-pinteresting.herokuapp.com request_id=0a07ed0f-2229-4f09-a112-a3760f26ac6f fwd="50.143.161.142" dyno=web.1 connect=7ms service=88ms status=500 bytes=1543
2014-05-29T19:19:49.089016+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PinsController#show as HTML
2014-05-29T19:19:49.086135+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/pins/3" for 50.143.161.142 at 2014-05-29 19:19:49 +0000
2014-05-29T19:19:49.134104+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 45ms
2014-05-29T19:19:49.135615+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-05-29T19:19:49.133890+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pins/show.html.erb within layouts/application (31.7ms)
2014-05-29T19:19:49.135618+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `pin' for #<#<Class:0x007ff9f4a7af80>:0x007ff9f3cf10f8>):
2014-05-29T19:19:49.135641+00:00 app[web.1]:      7: 
2014-05-29T19:19:49.135619+00:00 app[web.1]:      6: </p>
2014-05-29T19:19:49.135628+00:00 app[web.1]:     11: <%= link_to 'Back', pins_path %>
2014-05-29T19:19:49.086148+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/pins/3" for 50.143.161.142 at 2014-05-29 19:19:49 +0000
2014-05-29T19:19:49.133901+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pins/show.html.erb within layouts/application (31.7ms)
2014-05-29T19:19:49.134007+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 45ms
2014-05-29T19:19:49.135639+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `pin' for #<#<Class:0x007ff9f4a7af80>:0x007ff9f3cf10f8>):
2014-05-29T19:19:49.135647+00:00 app[web.1]:     11: <%= link_to 'Back', pins_path %>
2014-05-29T19:19:49.135623+00:00 app[web.1]:      8: <% if @pin.user == current_user %>
2014-05-29T19:19:49.135624+00:00 app[web.1]:      9:   <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_pin_path(pin) %>
2014-05-29T19:19:49.135640+00:00 app[web.1]:      6: </p>
2014-05-29T19:19:49.135644+00:00 app[web.1]:      9:   <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_pin_path(pin) %>
2014-05-29T19:19:49.135649+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/pins/show.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_pins_show_html_erb___2646305287935589538_70355765013340'
2014-05-29T19:19:49.089022+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PinsController#show as HTML
2014-05-29T19:19:49.135626+00:00 app[web.1]:     10: <% end %>
2014-05-29T19:19:49.135632+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-05-29T19:19:49.089071+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"id"=>"3"}
2014-05-29T19:19:49.089096+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"id"=>"3"}
2014-05-29T19:19:49.135631+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-05-29T19:19:49.135643+00:00 app[web.1]:      8: <% if @pin.user == current_user %>
2014-05-29T19:19:49.135621+00:00 app[web.1]:      7: 
2014-05-29T19:19:49.135646+00:00 app[web.1]:     10: <% end %>
2014-05-29T19:19:49.135629+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/pins/show.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_pins_show_html_erb___2646305287935589538_70355765013340'
2014-05-29T19:19:49.135652+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-05-29T19:19:49.135650+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-05-29T19:19:49.135637+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-05-29T19:19:49.526114+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/pins/3 host=lisa-pinteresting.herokuapp.com request_id=fc5e5e72-c0aa-4627-b9eb-8aafcc17060a fwd="50.143.161.142" dyno=web.1 connect=29ms service=170ms status=500 bytes=1543
2014-05-29T19:19:49.358930+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/pins/3" for 50.143.161.142 at 2014-05-29 19:19:49 +0000
2014-05-29T19:19:49.358940+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/pins/3" for 50.143.161.142 at 2014-05-29 19:19:49 +0000
2014-05-29T19:19:49.359939+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PinsController#show as HTML
2014-05-29T19:19:49.359986+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"id"=>"3"}
2014-05-29T19:19:49.501291+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pins/show.html.erb within layouts/application (118.8ms)
2014-05-29T19:19:49.501301+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pins/show.html.erb within layouts/application (118.8ms)
2014-05-29T19:19:49.359944+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PinsController#show as HTML
2014-05-29T19:19:49.503448+00:00 app[web.1]:      8: <% if @pin.user == current_user %>
2014-05-29T19:19:49.503465+00:00 app[web.1]:      6: </p>
2014-05-29T19:19:49.503455+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/pins/show.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_pins_show_html_erb___2646305287935589538_70355765611620'
2014-05-29T19:19:49.503456+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-05-29T19:19:49.503440+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-05-29T19:19:49.503457+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-05-29T19:19:49.503446+00:00 app[web.1]:      7: 
2014-05-29T19:19:49.503464+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `pin' for #<#<Class:0x007ff9f4a7af80>:0x007ff9f4a74e28>):
2014-05-29T19:19:49.503474+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/pins/show.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_pins_show_html_erb___2646305287935589538_70355765611620'
2014-05-29T19:19:49.503445+00:00 app[web.1]:      6: </p>
2014-05-29T19:19:49.503473+00:00 app[web.1]:     11: <%= link_to 'Back', pins_path %>
2014-05-29T19:19:49.503451+00:00 app[web.1]:     10: <% end %>
2014-05-29T19:19:49.503453+00:00 app[web.1]:     11: <%= link_to 'Back', pins_path %>
2014-05-29T19:19:49.501468+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 141ms
2014-05-29T19:19:49.359981+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"id"=>"3"}
2014-05-29T19:19:49.503467+00:00 app[web.1]:      7: 
2014-05-29T19:19:49.503471+00:00 app[web.1]:     10: <% end %>
2014-05-29T19:19:49.503470+00:00 app[web.1]:      9:   <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_pin_path(pin) %>
2014-05-29T19:19:49.503477+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-05-29T19:19:49.501474+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 141ms
2014-05-29T19:19:49.503443+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `pin' for #<#<Class:0x007ff9f4a7af80>:0x007ff9f4a74e28>):
2014-05-29T19:19:49.503462+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-05-29T19:19:49.503476+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-05-29T19:19:49.503449+00:00 app[web.1]:      9:   <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_pin_path(pin) %>
2014-05-29T19:19:49.503469+00:00 app[web.1]:      8: <% if @pin.user == current_user %>
2014-05-29T19:22:27+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-05-29T19:23:02+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: failed to compile Ruby app
2014-05-29T19:38:46+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-05-29T19:39:29+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: failed to compile Ruby app
```

I'm new to Rails and to programming. If anyone can help, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The errors are in the output:

```
   rake aborted!
   NameError: undefined local variable or method `config' for main:Object
   /tmp/build_32e2ee0e-d98a-4fbf-9662-a0c7aee58685/config/environments/production.rb:86:in `<top (required)>'
```

and also

```
2014-05-29T19:19:36.980508+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `pin' for #<#<Class:0x007ff9f4a7af80>:0x007ff9f4b73cc0>):
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm still learning how to read error logs. Turns out I had "end" in the wrong place in my production.rb file. Thanks again.